# What does the VB.NET UBound function ACTUALLY do, and why does the MSDN documentation appear to be inaccurate?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6-migration

**What does the UBound function *actually* do in VB.NET, and why doesn't the MSDN documentation appear to be accurate?**

According to the MSDN documentation ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95b8f22f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) the UBound function:

> Returns the highest available subscript for the indicated dimension of an array.

More specifically:

> The highest value the subscript for the specified dimension can contain. If Array has only one element, UBound returns 0. If Array has no elements, for example if it is a zero-length string, UBound returns -1.

But, in my testing the (and in some examples found in the documentation) the UBound function returns the **length** of an array instead of the **highest available subscript**:

[image: Image from MSDN documentation on the UBound function]

*It's also important to note that UBound returns 1 for an Array containing one element, not 0 as the documentation states.*

---

**In response to an answer:**

I now see that when you declare an array in vb.net you are declaring the highest desired subscript NOT the length of the array as in C#.

Understanding that, I now understand why UBound was returning 1 instead of 0 for an array declared `Dim c(1)`. Because this array will have the highest subscript of 1 thus giving it 2 elements. Further, to declare an array with only one element in vb.net it should be declared like this `Dim b(0)`.

[image]

Comment: Your arrays are probably starting at index 1 instead of index 0. Try actually accessing the indices to be sure, then try `Dim a(0 to 99, 0 to 4, 0 to 3) as Byte`.

Comment: [UBound](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Information.vb,163) is a wapped method of [Array.GetUpperBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns "the index of the last element of the specified dimension in the array".

Comment: Your screenshot headed "In response to an answer" has incorrect code - you need to specify an index for each dimension of the array, e.g. replace `a(UBound(a,1))` by `a(UBound(a,1), UBound(a,2), UBound(a,3))`

Comment: Your `Dim b(1) As Byte` is not an array with one element.  It is an array with 2 elements (indices 0 and 1).  In VB, when declaring an array, you specify the upper bound, not it's length.

Comment: I updated the screenshot with accurate code. Thanks for helping me clear up my understanding of UBound and Arrays in VB.NET. 
I have to say that I prefer the behavior of arrays in the C family languages I've worked with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation is accurate:

Your example:

```
Dim a(100,5,4)
```

is the same as (*)

```
Dim a(0 To 100, 0 To 5, 0 To 4)
```

`UBound(a,1)` returns the highest available subscript of the first dimension, which is 100 (there are actually 101 elements, indexed from 0 to 100).

(*) Actually in VB6 and VBA you can override the default lower bound using the Option Base statement.  But if you don't do this (and you shouldn't!), it will default to 0.

Personally I always use `0 To N` when declaring VB arrays, to be absolutely explicit and not to rely on the Option Base setting.  `a(N)` or `a(0 To N)` declare an array with N+1 elements, indexed from 0 To N, and the latter syntax makes this clearer IMHO.

Note that in VBA/VB6 (from which VB.NET was derived) it is possible to use any lower bound, so you can also declare an array as, say:

```
Dim a(500 to 600)
```

If you want to write code that can iterate over such arrays, you should always use:

```
For nIndex = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
```

> It's also important to note that UBound returns 1 for an Array containing one element

Not true - the following array has one element, and `UBound(a)` returns 0:

```
Dim a(0)
```

or

```
Dim a(0 To 0)
```

The array

```
Dim a(1)
```

is the same as:

```
Dim a(0 To 1)
```

and has two elements `a(0)` and `a(1)`.  `LBound` returns 0 and `UBound` returns 1, just as you'd expect.

One final point: UBound(a) will return -1 for an empty array (no elements).  AFAIK you can't create such an array with VB6/VBA code, but you can get one returned from code written in other languages, including VB.NET

Comment: `Option Base 1` was an old VB6 thing as was `Dim Sales(1990 To 2015)`  neither are supported in VB.NET even with the Compatibility layer

Comment: Why would you create an array where the starting index wouldn't be 0?

Comment: Regular people used to start counting at 1, Office was a major influence.  Dim a() As Integer = {} produces an UBound of -1.